# R: selecting a column in data.frame by knowing a value in a given row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
A <- c(1:10)
B <- c(2:11)
C <- c(3:12)

df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

How can I select a column knowing a value in a particular row.

eg row1, value 2   gives df$B
   row7, value 9 gives df$C
   row2, value 2 gives df$A

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `names` and `which`:

```
> names(df1)[which(df1[1, ] == 2)]
[1] "B"
> names(df1)[which(df1[7, ] == 9)]
[1] "C"
```

Comment: Also `names(df1)[df1[1,] %in% 2]` can help. Or `names(df1)[df1[1,] == 2]` to avoid `which(·)` ;)